# Identifying Chinese Artist of Two Beautiful Artworks (c. 1980s)

Tags: character-identification, seal

I've recently come into possession of two beautiful works of Chinese art, seemingly by the same artist as the seal and artistic style are a definite match. I'd like to identify the artist but have absolutely zero knowledge of the Chinese language. Appreciate any help you experts might be willing to lend this amateur art collector! Photos below:

[image: Artist seal]

[[image: Calligraphy for Painting 1- Palatial Scene][2]]
[![Palatial Scene - Painting 1[image: Cranes - Painting 2]

Answer (score 0):

in the 2nd picture: the title is “慶與鶴舞”, roughly means “joy with cranes’ dancing”

the next line is “丁卯春二月吉勻x吳門畫苑作”; that [in] the second month of spring [of lunar calendar], of the year 丁卯 (since you think that it’s a product of 1980s, it would be 1987)

“吉勻” most likely is the painter’s name

“x” not yet recognised, though semantically it should be “於” (at)

“吳門畫苑作”, roughly means “made at a studio in 吳門, aka 蘇州”

edited

Comment: This cursive writing of 於 is seen at https://ibb.co/WHLTQp2. Also, should the first character of the title be 慶 rather than 興?

Comment: @lilysirius, omg yes, it should be “慶”, my apologies ^o^

Comment: Thank you to you both for this great information! Do you think it is possible to find any information about the artist on the internet? I have not had any success so far.

Comment: Also - when I drop the artist's name into google translate, I am given the translation of 'Kyrgyzstan'; this is interesting as I purchased these paintings from a woman who spent many years living in the middle east. Do you think it's possible these works are from Kyrgyzstan?

Comment: @honebone89, Kyrgyzstan? it’s hard to tell 